# VirtualBox: Simulate network and DHCP Server - cant reach hosts

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I have 4 Virtual Machines with VirtualBox and I want to set up a virtual network like this:
[image: http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w522/derTimo/zwischenstand3_zpsc231137d.png]

The VMs have multiple `eth` interfaces using "Internal Networking" mode in Virtualbox.

My goal is to be able to alter the network traffic between the two Softphones with a tool called Dummynet which is going to be on the DHCP Server node.

I set up dhcp3 on the **DHCP Server** with the following `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` and the following  `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration:

[image]

The other VMs have static IPs assigned according to the first picture.

-->However, I can't ping between the hosts and the DHCP server. What am I missing here?

Thank you :)

**Note:** Softphone1, Softphone2 and SIP-Server are running on KUBUNTU and the DHCP-Server VM is running on UBUNTU.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found the answer by myself.

In VirtualBox, the additional ethernet adapters that are connected to the "Internal Network" have to have the same **name** if they are on the same subnet.

For example in my case subnet `20.0.0.0` that includes `Softphone1(eth1)` and `DHCP-Server(eth1)` is connected to the "Internal Network" `neta`. In both VMs network settings in VirtualBox the name for the Internal Network has to be the same, so the clients can reach each other. They are now virtually on the same network. Now I am able to ping from the DHCP-Server to the Softphone and vice versa.

I hope someone can profit from my problem and solution.